# Eclipse error while installing eUML2 Plugins for Juno SR2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

While attempting to install eUML2 for Eclipse Juno SR2 on Windows XP SP2 , I get the following error :

Software being installed: EclipseDatabase Modeler 4.0.0.20120830 (com.soyatec.database.feature.group 4.0.0.20120830)
  Missing requirement: EclipseDatabase Modeler 4.0.0.20120830 (com.soyatec.database.feature.group 4.0.0.20120830) requires 'org.eclipse.uml2.feature.group [4.0.0.v20120604-0919,5.0.0)' but it could not be found

Can anybody suggest the resolution for the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Which package of Eclipse did you use? It may be that it required the modeling kind;
http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-modeling-tools/junosr2